# How to get all the row values for 1 particular type from the below tables

Tags: sql, join

I have the below two tables.

[image: Table Value]

[image: other image]

I need to get bill_id(details table),amount(details table) for all the type(Value Table)='Card'. I have used the below query but it is returning only 1 row instead of all the expected row. What correction i need to do here

```
SELECT 
   bill_id
  ,amount
FROM details d
JOIN value v ON d.id = v.id
WHERE d.id IN (
    SELECT v.id
    FROM value
    WHERE v.type = 'Card'
    );
```

Below is the output i am getting and the expected output
[OutPut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3lYQ.jpg)

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not as images or links to images. Also take a look at [mcve].

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code; it's not optimal, but it should work. Without sample data, current results, and expected results, though, you're just going to get people continuing to guess. See [How to post a SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) and edit your question with additional detail.

Comment: Apologies. I have added the expected output and the output i am getting by using the mentioned code.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try:

```
    SELECT bill_id 
       ,amount 
    FROM details d 
        INNER JOIN value v ON d.id = v.id
    WHERE v.type ='Card'
```

Let me know if that doesn't work

Comment: it still returns only 1 row instead of all the rows with type as 'Card' . I am expecting total of 5 rows in the output.

Comment: ok you will need to provide the data or at least query the below and let me know what it returns 
````
SELECT bill_id 
       ,amount 
      ,v.type
    FROM details d 
        INNER JOIN value v ON d.id = v.id

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply?

```
Select bill_id ,amount 
from details d join value v 
on d.id = v.id
where v.type ='Card';
```

Let us know if this doesn't give you the desired answer. Posting a sample input and expectd output would help.

Comment: It returns me only 1 row in output but i am expecting all the rows(5) in expected output.

Comment: This is exactly the same query as posted in Tobias' answer.

Comment: @AB_5 please post the output and expected output inline (don't use external links). Also we need the input data as well. From what I can see, there's nothing wrong with this query (nor is with the logic or your own query).